# Existence or construction of kernel of order $m$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm looking for a function $K$ satisfying $\int K(y)dy=1$, $\int y^jK(y)dy=0$ for $1\leq j<m$, and $\int|y|^mK(y)dy<\infty$, and finally $\int|y|K^2(y)dy<\infty$.

In the statistical literature such a function is known as a *kernel of order* $m$. Finding a second order kernel is easy: just take any symmetric probability density; popular choices are Gaussian, $\mathrm{Uni}([-\frac12,\frac12])$, Epanechnikov $K(x)=\frac34(1-x^2)\mathbf1_{|x|\leq1}$, Biweight $K(x)=\frac{15}{16}(1-x^2)^2\mathbf1_{|x|\leq1}$ or Triweight $K(x)=\frac{35}{32}(1-x^2)^3\mathbf1_{|x|\leq1}$.

An idea I had was Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization: suppose we use $K(x)=\frac1{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, then the Chebyshev polynomial of degree $m$, $T_m$, satisfies $\langle T_m,x^j\rangle_K=0$ for $0\leq j<m$, meaning that all conditions are satisfied, expect for the first one: if we use $\tilde K(x)=T_m(x)K(x)$, $$\int \tilde K(y)dy=\langle T_m,1\rangle_K=0\neq1,$$ and I do not see how to fix this problem. EDIT: the condition $\int|y|K^2(y)dy<\infty$ is neither satisfied, but this can be fixed, for example, by orthogonalizing w.r.t. the Gaussian density, yielding the Hermite polynomials. Then the above applies: we still have $\int \tilde K(y)dy\neq1$.

At different sources online, it is stated that ``higher-order kernels are obtained by multiplying a second-order kernel by an $(2m-1)$-order polynomial in $x^2$''. However, I do not see why this yields a function satisfying the needed conditions.

Any help or reference is much appriciated. I'm looking either for a construction or a specific example, if such a closed form expression is valid for every $m$.

EDIT: This question came from the context of density estimation in nonparametric estimation, where we use kernel estimators. If we let $K$ be a p.d.f. of a random variable with mean zero and unit variance, then it is true that the mean integrated square error of the kernel estimator for an optimal bandwith of order $n^{-1/5}$ is of order $n^{-4/5}$. Then it is stated that using a parametric model, we could achieve an error of order $n^{-1}$. However, using a kernel of order $m$, which I'm asking about in this question, we can take bandwith of order $n^{-1/(2m+1)}$, leading to a mean integrated square error of order $n^{-(2m)/(2m+1)}$. Therefore, by taking a kernel of sufficiently high order, the parametric rate can be approximated to the desired accuracy. See $\S5.2$ in [these lecture notes](https://vu.amsterdamstatlab.nl/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Asymp-dictaat.pdf) based on the book *Asymptotic Statistics* by van der Vaart (they are English, ignore first 2 pages) for the details. Here it is stated that we can just take such a kernel, but it is not explained why such a kernel should exist.

Comment: Hi! the question you are asking for seems very interesting. Where did it come from? do you have any references?

Comment: Hi @rarwoan, thank you. I made an edit to explain where this question came from and included a reference on this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K(x)$ be a probability density function and take the ansatz $\tilde{K}(x)=p(x)K(x)$ for our higher order kernel. Notation wise, let $p(x)=\sum_i x^{i}p_i$, and let  $M_i$ be the ith moment of $K$, thus $M_i=\int x^{i} K(x)dx$.

$0=\int x^l \tilde{K}(x)dx$ becomes the linear constraint $\sum_i p_i M_{i+l}=0$. Similarly we have the constraint $\sum_i p_iM_i=1$. So we want to show that the matrix $\left(\begin{array} {ccc} M_0 & \dots & M_{m+1}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\ M_{l} &\dots & M_{l+m+1}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\ M_{m+1} &\dots& M_{m+1+m+1} \end{array}\right)$ is invertible.

A matrix of this form is called a Hankel matrix, and is often invertible. For example, if we take $K(x)=1_{x\in [0,4]}\sqrt{-1+4/x}/2\pi$, then $M_i$ is a Catalan number, and it is well known that the matrix always has determinant 1 (see the wikipedia article on Catalan numbers for example). Moreover, the finiteness conditions will be satisfied because $K$ has finite support.